# Pandas: Add null values in two columns to null

Tags: pandas, null

I have a table like the one below.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.5 | Baseline |
| NaN | NaN | Baseline |
| 2.0 | NaN | Baseline |

I want to insert a column after summing the first two columns, and want a result like below.

| A | B | Sum | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.5 | 2.5 | Baseline |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | Baseline |
| 2.0 | NaN | 2.0 | Baseline |

The code I'm trying out is, df.insert(2, 'Sum', df[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1))

But I'm getting the below result.

| A | B | Sum | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.5 | 2.5 | Baseline |
| NaN | NaN | 0.0 | Baseline |
| 2.0 | NaN | 2.0 | Baseline |

I would like to keep the sum of NaNs as a NaN in the sum column. Is there any short way to do this?

Some posts suggest, I can do (df['A'].fillna('') + df['B'].fillna('')).replace('', np.nan)). But float columns do not allow replacing Nan by ''. And I have multiple columns to sum and want to avoid a long formula. Will be grateful for any suggestion!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output.

Comment: That [mre] would in particular let us know what null object you have exactly, in case it matters. Are they all np.nan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
res = np.where(df[['A', 'B']].notna().any(axis=1),
               df[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1), np.NaN)
df.insert(2, 'Sum', res)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     A    B  Sum         C
0  1.0  1.5  2.5  Baseline
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  Baseline
2  2.0  NaN  2.0  Baseline
```

Without numpy, you can do:

```
res = df[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1)[df[['A', 'B']].notna().any(axis=1)]
df.insert(2, 'Sum', res)
```

Another way:

```
res = df[['A', 'B']].fillna(0, limit=1, axis=1).sum(axis=1, skipna=False)
```